# How to make JComponent Global

Tags: java, jlabel, public, jcomponent

I create a JLabel in one Method and i would like to access it
in my ItemListener. How can I make my JLabel "Public static"?

```
public class MainTicketPrinter implements ItemListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainTicketPrinter().ticket();
    }

    public void ticket() {
        JLabel lblTicket= new JLabel("This is a Ticket");
        lblTicket.addItemListener(this);      
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        lblTicket.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If u want just to do that you can use public static JLabel lblTicket= new JLabel("This is a Ticket"); in class level. But think about your design first.

Comment: While @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne's comment and Matthijs answer have the answer you are looking for, you actually don't need to use public static for this case, because you are accessing it from the ItemListener itself. If you will have two MainTicketPrinter's you can get into trouble with that static variable.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class MainTicketPrinter implements ItemListener{
    public static JLabel lblTicket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainTicketPrinter().ticket();
    }

    public void ticket() {
        lblTicket= new JLabel("This is a Ticket");
        lblTicket.addItemListener(this);    
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        lblTicket.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

edit: I'm not sure but perhaps it is possible to access the item throug the event that is called?

Comment: Waht if I have 200+ JComponents, is it still good practise to have all of them declared on class level?

Comment: @user3458556 Declaring something at the class level should be done if all the objects which are part of that class share that common property, for example if you want to print all tickets with the same color, then if makes sense to hold that color at class level. Any other property which is **object dependent** should be declared for each object individually, i.e. without `static`.

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful information. But this would tell me it should not be declared at class level since i only want that certain label for a certain ticket. But if I declare it in the methode i can not access it in the itemListener. Is there maybe a way to have the "itemStateChaged" inside the ticket() methode?

Comment: @user3458556 I think you are confused about this. Instance variables belong to an object and are defined without the `static` keyword. Class variable are defined once for every object that will be created from that class. Putting methods one inside the other is not possible. Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html for variables and the Java Programmer 1 gentle introduction into Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/certification/javase-7-programmer1.html#basics if you still need help with the Java basics.